# Securely Share Partner Dashboards

Tags: community, sharing, dashboard, partner-communities, reports-folder

My goal is to share dashboards on partner community.
I created opportunities report and dashboard for partners.

when i logged in as partner 1 i can see partner 2 related record on dashboard.
Of course I used the show only my opportunities(The partners contact does not own the opportunity but they see it anyway), but it did not help.
What is the best way of doing that.

Creating different report per each partner by filtering the partner account field seems like a complete waste of my time.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily resolved by setting up dynamic dashboard on lightning or classic UI.
Just make sure you have the permission Manage Dynamic Dashboards.
Than just add view dashboard as dashboard viewer, and the viewer sees only records he have access to.